# Does Mob appear in One Punch Man?

Tags: one-punch-man, mob-psycho-100

I was reading One Punch Man chapter #100 and in the cover there is a guy who looks like Mob from Mob Psycho 100. Is it him?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wanted to let you know that *that is not the cover for the 100th chapter* but rather for **Chapter 65** titled *Sisters*.

Regardless, those are indeed characters from *Mob Psycho 100*. Starting from the left, we have Dimple hovering above some people then Mob and Tome (president of Telepathy club). [image]

As a side note, from what I could translate from the description above Mob and Tome, the TV アニメ ... モブ サイコ 100 ...東京 MX... means TV Anime ... Mob Psycho 100 ... Tokyo MX. This chapter might have been released before the start of broadcast of the *Mob Psycho 100* anime and the cameos of characters, together with the description, was probably meant as an announcement to the new anime that was to be broadcasted on Tokyo MX.

This does not mean however that Mob appears in OPM or is set in the OPM universe. That is only a cover photo, not an actual scene in the manga story.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the chapter 100th Punch: Light
[image: Chapter 100]

**Mob of Mob Psycho 100 is definitely not there**

All the characters in the cover page:

- Saitama (inside the gift box)
- Genos (Above the gift box)
- King (inside the sock/shoe)
- Child Emperor (with the robot reindeer)
- Fubuki
- Tornado
- Garou (near the bed)
- (forgot the name of the kid always with garou)

**EDIT:**

If you are talking about that chapter, that is **chapter 65: Sisters**.

And yes! Mob, Tome and Dimple from Mob Psycho 100 is there, but only in the cover page. It is also stated in the [One Punch Man Wiki: Chapter 65 (Sisters)](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_65)

Comment: that's not the image I'm talking about

Comment: You've said **cover page of chapter 100**, that's the cover page

Comment: The chapter numbering for the manga is very messed up on a lot of sites, as Murata has frequently released chapters in chunks, which some places have (sometimes) interpreted as each being individual chapters.  A lot of them have been getting corrected to the official numberings, but possibly Pablo was using a site which has not.